# Cron running php script every 1 min not connect to DB

Tags: mysql, database, cron

I have added the follow cron command and it runs fine.

```
php -q /home/****/***.com/****/check.php
```

But when I try to add a database connection the follow

```
 define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
 define("DB_USER", "system");
 define("DB_PASS", "***");
 define("DB_NAME", "system");


 mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error());
```

or include a db.php file the cron stops running, I dont get no errors as soon I remove it database connection it works again.

FULL CODE

```
 define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
 define("DB_USER", "system");
 define("DB_PASS", "***");
 define("DB_NAME", "system");


 mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error()); 
 $result44 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ") or die(mysql_error()); 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result44)) {
    if(time_elapsed_string($row['lastConnection']) >= 60){
    //mysql_query("UPDATE table SET powerStatus='-1' WHERE  id='".$row['id']."'") or die (mysql_error());

    }else{
        //mysql_query("UPDATE table SET powerStatus='1' WHERE  id='".$row['id']."'") or die (mysql_error());

    }
}
```

Why is it not working when I add a DB connection?

Comment: Any error you are getting..

Comment: i am not getting any errors :(

Answer (score 0):

Please use:-

```
require_once(__DIR__."/../settings.php"); // PHP >=5.3
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/../settings.php"); // PHP <5.3
```

Ref: [PHP script run via cron does not connect to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514623/php-script-run-via-cron-does-not-connect-to-database)